# Arduino IDE Unable to detect ZumoMotor.H ( PIXY PET )

Tags: c++, arduino-leonardo, library, arduino-ide

recently i trying to make the pixy pet work for my project. (https://learn.adafruit.com/pixy-pet-robot-color-vision-follower-using-pixycam/playing-with-your-pet).

I used the given code for the arduino IDE, but i keep on getting this error Arduino: 1.5.7 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Leonardo"

sketch_sep17a.ino:27:24: fatal error: ZumoMotors.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.

This report would have more information with "Show verbose output during compilation" enabled in File > Preferences.

The Code, im using, was given by the official maker of the Pixy Pet. Please have a look. ( https://learn.adafruit.com/pixy-pet-robot-color-vision-follower-using-pixycam/the-code)

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to install the ZumoMotors library.

There's one available at the following link, although I don't know for sure that it's the same one your Pixy Pet requires:

- https://github.com/pololu/zumo-shield

That page includes instructions on how to install the libraries. If you get stuck, there's more help in the official Arduino documentation:

- http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries